# Array mapping on elasticsearch for range filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a text column on MySQL which is a bunch of numbers separated by "|" and I need to apply some range filters on it.

I have a memory stick item, with storage of 32|64|128 on this field, and another one with 16|32|64. When I filter with range between 32 and 128, both of them must be hits.

Comment: You'll need to provide some more info if you want people to help you. Your current mapping, one or two sample documents and the query you have currently would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that you want to copy all data from MySQL to Elasticsearch and have efficient queries like "all memory sticks which have a capacity between X and Y".

I'd just split the string from `|`s and store the resulting array to a field which is mapped as `integer` type. These can be efficiently found by a [range filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-range-filter.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've made a trigger on mysql that split these values into a new related table. I guess it worked just fine.